# Specify TFS backglog tree items

Tags: tfs

Is there any option to configure TFS backlog tree items I'v marked bellow?

[image]

EDIT:

I would like to create target structure that looks like:

- Current
- Future
- Experimental
- Other

Comment: Not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve. Do you want to create a query with the items in those sprints?

Comment: I would like to have for example: Current, Future, Experimental, Other categories for my sprints. So I need to customize existing structure.

Comment: What's an experimental sprint?

Comment: @JohnSaunders It's a sprint that contains some experimental futures. But it's only a example name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way you can configure the tree on the left panel but since you are using TFS 2013 (also available in 2012) you can use **Tags** to mark the backlog items that are **Experimental** or **Other**.

**Add tags to work items to categorize and filter lists:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn132606(v=vs.120).aspx

Other option is to add a custom field to work items which is not recommended as its painful when you want to upgrade later on.

**Modify or add a custom work item type:** http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh409273.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you essentially want to add extra metadata to sprints.  Unfortunately this is not currently possible (the only metadata supported today is Name, Start Date, End Date).

What some people have done in the past (prior to the Agile Planning tooling), is introduce a Work Item Type called Sprint, then they can define custom fields against it and surface the data in WI Queries.

I suppose you could define a new WI Type and try to associate it with Iterations, but I wouldn't recommend it.